# Using selector on a Jquery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

i got a question (i guess it is really simple but i really can't find it cause it's really specific).

I'd like to find how to use selector on a Jquery Object representing a DOM element.

Here is an exemple of what i want to do.

HTML:

```
<div id="template">
    <button class="buttonRemove"></button>
    ...A Lot of other HTML Content...
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var myTemplate = $("#template").clone(true);
myTemplate.attr("id","a_new_customized_id");
myTemplate.A_WAY_TO_SELECT_BUTTON_WITH_CLASS_REMOVE.hide();
```

I'd like to do that cause of two reason :
I'm using my real template for some differents functions (Like Showing informations that can be delete, and some others that can't)

Thx !

EDIT: Thx everyone for your responses. I tried a lot of thing like "$.myTemplate.("selector")" before you gave me the solution.

I just found an other solution that is :

```
$('#buttonRemove',myTemplate)
```

If you use a 2nd parameter in the selector method, it will be use as the domain of research for the selector. (Default : document)

Comment: [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: you want jquery find http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: myTemplate.find(":button.buttonRemove").hide() will hide all buttons of class "buttonRemove" from inside myTemplate. Add a ":first" at the end of the selector to only get the first button found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myTemplate.A_WAY_TO_SELECT_BUTTON_WITH_CLASS_REMOVE.hide()
```

is written like this, ( let's say your class is "remove")

```
myTemplate.find('button.remove').hide()
```

Comment: Thx, that what i wanted to find :) ! Didn't know this one.

Comment: Be careful with cloning the element though. You will get confused on what you are manipulating. Maybe name it 'myTemplate_Clone' or something.

Comment: In my real code, i'm just using my Template to generate Tabs for JQuery accordion (with a specific organization) this is why i use clones.

Answer (score 3):

```
myTemplate.find('button.buttonRemove').hide();
```

This will have no effect if the cloned element is not appended to the DOM later/earlier.

Comment: Of course ;) ! I was just showing a little exemple of what i needed, not exactly what i'll do :) ! Thx anyway !

Answer (score 1):

```
myTemplate.find('button.remove').hide();
```

This find in myTemplate for button with remove class.